# Using mathpazo's summation sign instead of newtxmath's

Tags: fonts, xetex, math-fonts

I have the following problem: I use the package `newtxmath` with option `minion` in order to use the Minion Pro font by Adobe for math typesetting (DO NOT TRY setting). However, the summation sign of `newtxmath` basically looks like crap. I figured the summation sign of the package `mathpazo`would be a better match.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[ \sum \]
\end{document}
```

Yields the "ugly" summation sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
\[ \sum \]
\end{document}
```

Yields the beautiful summation sign.

Now, i want to use `newtxmath` for all other things but the sum, which i would like to have the `mathpazo symbol`.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsCM}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\txsum\sum
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"50}
```

Replaces the summation sign with the default computer modern. I believe, the solution may look very similar. I have tried substituting `mathpazo` for `cmex` in the above samble without success.

Any help is very welcome!

(Note: I use XeTeX for compilation, however I suppose a solution for pdfLaTeX will likely translate.)

Comment: not directly related but don't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with xetex (it does nothing other than warn that it should not be used)

Comment: yes that is correct @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look in `mathpazo.sty` you find

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}  {OMX}{zplm}{m}{n}
```

so you want `zplm` not `mathpazo` as the font family name.

Comment: That is correct! I will mark this answer as solved, once StackExchange allows me. Thank you so much! @DavidCarlisle